# why won't Blender. files convert to FBX files in Unity 5.0

Tags: blender, fbx, unity3d-editor

After  Putting a model in unity from Blender it sais:

Blender could not convert the .blend file to FBX file.
You need to use Blender 2.45-2.49 or 2.58 and later versions for direct Blender import to work.

Note that i have Blender 2.71
    UnityEditorInternal.InternalEditorUtility:ProjectWindowDrag(HierarchyProperty, Boolean)
    UnityEditor.DockArea:OnGUI()

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Found out you go to :

FILE/Export and choose

Answer (score 0):

I found this, how to solve this issue. open the **.blender** file in Blender then click the **file** at the top left corner, then **import** change to **.fbx** and save. when you are done then close the Blender.
Hope that solve the problem.